# MPAndroidChart chart value selected listener is invoked during scroll

Tags: android, scrollview, mpandroidchart

I have two bar charts one below another in a scrollview. Both of them have chart value select listeners attached to them. When I try to scroll on the screen, the value selected listener is being invoked. Any way to suppress this and trigger the listener only when the bar is clicked actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching, the solution was setting
chart.setHighlightPerDragEnabled(false) as mentioned [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/2808#issuecomment-290301497)